# Jquery: Building navigation including page inside body

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I builded for my home page (index.php) a navigation bar, where I can click on one of the available links (anchors). Selecting one link a new body is loaded inside my page (index.php) that contains this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myselector a').click(function(e) {
          var url = $(this).attr('href');
          $('#body').load(url);
          e.preventDefault();
      });
  });
```

this works good.

But, now after loading new page page1.php inside the body of index.php I have this trouble:

My `page1.php` contains a form, and after the submission I need to reload the index.php with `page2.php` inside. How can I perfrom this?

**Note: I edit my question: If you think that now it is clear can you upvote plese? (I was banned for this question and I can't post other question)**

Comment: Is your problem, that your code doesn't work with the newly inserted DOM-content and a click on a link inside your loaded content doesn't trigger your eventhandler?

Comment: Not properly @Johannes  I've edit my answer for more details

Comment: Your clarification is a bit confusing about submitting a form. All information should be included in the question.

Comment: @Joseph82 I don't see the problem? If you use the snippet from my answer the file your link points to - page1.php will get loaded into your body element. What more do you need? You certainly do not always need to reload your index.php - since you're swapping out the body content anyway.

Comment: @Joseph82 Did you solve your problem?

Comment: I'm sure your suggestion was useful @Johannes, but I'm newbie and I preferred to come back to more easy solution avoiding other downvotes with my answers.

Comment: Can you upvote if the question is more clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to catch events from nodes inserted at a later point you need to use event-delegation, for example like this:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#body').load(url);
});
```

This way every click on a link, which is a childnode of `body` will cause the eventhandler to fire. If you do not want to target all links, but just specific ones you can do that by adding a class to them and the selector.